# Replace many phrases from a comma seperated txt file

Tags: batch-file, replace, text-files

Any body know a way I can not just replace a phrase at a time?
Say I have a txt file with a phrase , the phrase to be replaced for example:

```
111 , 232


122 , 324
```

and so on..

each phrase on the left needs to be replaced with the phrase on the right and each new replacement is in a new line. Is there a way to replace multiple phrases from loading a txt file instead of one-by-one frustrating replaces?

Comment: You need to you use `sed`. In order to tell you the exact command, we need a little bit more detail. Like a sample input and output file.

Comment: Excuse me. I think I don't understand what you need. Are you talking about *two* files, one with multiple replacement phrases (like the above) and *another* file with the text you want to process? If so, what "and each new replacement is in a new line" means? Post a sample input and output, as Raihan suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation you'd want to approach this in different ways.  I would take Raihan's advice if applicable in your working environment.  If applicable, you may also be able to do the replacements in vim.  If you must use a batch script, this should help, though it is off the top of my head and may require some tweaking on your part, as have no windows machine to test it on:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set new_file=your_new_or_temporary_file.txt
set name_of_your_txt_file_of_replacements=your_replacements_file_name.txt
set name_of_your_txt_file_of_content_to_replace=your_file_of_content_to_replace.txt

if EXIST "!new_file!" del "!new_file!"

for /f 'eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=,' %%l in ('type "!name_of_your_txt_file_of_replacements!"') do (
  set existing_text=%%l
  set replacement_text=%%i
  @REM: Based on your example you will have trailing and leading blanks
  @REM: See this site to trim your existing_text and replacement_text
  @REM: Source: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!replacement_text!") do set replacement_text=%%a

  for /l %%a in (1,1,31) do (
    if "!existing_text:~-1!"==" " set existing_text=!existing_text:~0,-1!
    if "!replacement_text:~-1!"==" " set replacement_text=!replacement_text:~0,-1!
  )

  echo replacing !existing_text! with !replacement_text!...

  for /f 'eol=; tokens=1 delims=' %%c in ('type   "!name_of_your_txt_file_of_content_to_replace!"') do (
    set line=%%c
    for /f 'eol=; tokens=1 delims=' %%c in ('echo !line! ^| findstr /i /c:"!existing_text!"') do (        
      for /f 'eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=,' %%c in ("!existing_text!,!replacement_text!") do
      set line=!line:%%c=%%d!
    )
    @REM::Just reread your specs, and if you want the new file to just contain
    @REM::  the replacement text, then do this instead:
    @REM::  echo !replacement_text! >> !new_file!
    @REM::Otherwise, copy of existing file with updated text

    echo !line! >> !new_file!
  )
)

@REM:: Compare your original file with !new_file! and make sure it is all good.
@REM:: Once you have to code to where it is all good do this

mv "!new_file!" "!name_of_your_txt_file_of_content_to_replace!"
```

If you run into issues let me know.  Good luck! :)